# Antlr adding additional parameters to visit methods, accommodations for continuation passing style

Tags: java, antlr, programming-languages, continuation-passing

I am trying to do continuation passing style for a simple programming language made with antlr. Typically you would have an eval procedure that takes as arguments the expression to be evaluated as well as the continuation of that expression. I guess it would be quite elegant to add an additional continuation parameter to the visitor's visit methods (or for the listener).

However, when I generate the parser code with the antlr jar, the visit methods only take one parameter, namely the context (i.e., the tree).

So my question is, how can I add additional parameters to the visit methods such that I get this:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 *
 * <p>The default implementation does nothing.</p>
 */
@Override public void enterStart(Parser.StartContext ctx, Continuation cnt) { }
```

Instead of the currently auto generated code:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 *
 * <p>The default implementation does nothing.</p>
 */
@Override public void enterStart(Parser.StartContext ctx) { }
```

If it is not possible to add additional parameters to the visitor's visit methods, how would one accommodate the **continuation passing style** in antlr?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could make a private version of the tool templates to generate what you want.

Comment: I don’t think I get what you mean, could you elaborate please?

Comment: Modify [this code](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/tool/resources/org/antlr/v4/tool/templates/codegen/CSharp/CSharp.stg) then follow the build procedure [here](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/building-antlr.md). You will have a jar to generate your parser code with CPS. Use "find" to find the jar.

Comment: That seems like a big hastle, I think it might be simpler to just write one eval procedure to dispatch on the context if you get what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

> ow can I add additional parameters to the visit methods

You cannot add any parameters to `enter...`, `exit...` or `visit...` methods.

Comment: Any suggestions for the cps part?

Comment: What do you mean by "cps part"?